# Accessing Local Files From online Web Application

Tags: java, spring, file, web, bufferedreader

I have a web application which can traverse a directory and give you the file list from that directory.

From `http://localhpst:8080/searchEngine` it is working perfectly fine

but when I am deploying it on a sever then, It is not displaying any result.

what can be the reason??..is it permission issue???..if yes, how can I grant the permissions using Java Program.

I am ready to provide username password.

i have all the files in  my local directory..checkout this link  http://searchengineenv.jelastic.dogado.eu/searchEngine/  I am passing local directory path and word to search in that folders file.

It is working fine in my local but not working when i put it online.

Comment: It can look at files on the machine the web app runs on. The server probably doesn't have the same folder structure as your local machine. Although the Java based server might not have permissions to read/write local files. That's a possibility.

Comment: Is there some error? What do the server logs look like?

Comment: "I am ready to provide username password." Not a good idea.

Comment: I am the royal prince of Zamunda. I will help you in exchange for your username, password, and credit card number...

Comment: @LukeWillis "i am ready to provide Username and password" through my application to get the access...but i want to know how can i access it...

Comment: How do you put the files you want to search on that server? And I agree with @LeeMeador, sounds like a wrong access/permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to have a program traverse a filesystem is to have that program reside on the same machine. It becomes very tricky to have a remote machine's filesystem accessible by external users, between permissions and user logins and roles, and it all of course depends on the filesystem you run.

In order for it to work, you'll need the application to be deployed on your local machine. You could then use a separate application deployed to a different server that could communicate with the local app and present the results to a webpage or what have you.

(This goes on the assumption that when you say "deployed to a server" you mean a different machine)